# Print output only if it's going to start at the beginning of the line?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm trying to make my program output a sentence but only if it will start at the beginning of the line. For example, if this is my current console window:

> Hello World! [Do not print if text is going to start here]
>   [Print if text is going to start here]

Is there a way to check if the current output line is empty? Or even the position my new output will start at?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very highly OS and Shell(/settings) dependent.

Comment: ...or maybe you want to force output into the beginning of line - instead of just checking to print or not to print. In such case use `printf("\rYour text")`. But maybe this is not necessary what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C isn't going to track the state of the standard output. You'll have to do it yourself. At every point where you generate output, set a flag that indicates if you ended the line or not.

Comment: I'm writing the program in C but I guess I could use a flag. Thanks!

Comment: @Uqi Now how in the world did I get Python out of that question? You're right, the answer's the same in either case.